# Center Container & Z-Index

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to center align the following dropdown and just can't get it to work. Furthermore I have a problem with the layers, unfortunately the dropdown is displayed under the following container. Can someone help me? Does anyone have an idea?

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 98;
  max-height: 0;
  min-width: 160px;
  transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 160px;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" for="btnControl">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your full code of issues? In here, there's no issues.

Comment: Do you want the `.dropdown` element centered on the page, or do you want the text of the child anchor elements centered?

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 98;
  max-height: 0;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 160px;
  transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 160px;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" for="btnControl">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```